# Zend_Loader_Autoload_Module does not load module classes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader, zend-framework-modules

> **My mistake** - I didn't read the error messages properly - I was still `var_dump`ing `Zend_Loader_Autoload` in the bootstrap which was causing a "headers already sent" exception. Remember to try without debugging output!

I have a modular application running on ZF 1.11.11 with this directory structure:

```
application/
  Bootstrap.php
  modules/
    default/
      controllers/
      models/
      views/
    manager/
      Bootstrap.php
      controllers/
      models/
      forms/
      views
  layouts/
  configs/
```

Relevant `application.ini` declarations:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

Essentially my problem is that a controller in the manager module cannot load a form in the `forms/` directory of the manager directory. `var_dump`ing `Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()` shows that all the `Application_` maps are defined, (although to the wrong place, `/application` rather than `/default`) and no maps are defined for `Manager_`.

What confuses me is that the Bootstrap.php in `manager/` is loaded, which means that the module has been detected. This bootstrap simply extends `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`.

Is there some arcane configuration value I'm missing here? The documentation seems to be quite sparse on this (would also love some in-depth explanation on this).

Answer (score 0):

**My mistake** - I didn't read the error messages properly - I was still `var_dump`ing `Zend_Loader_Autoload` in the bootstrap which was causing a "headers already sent" exception. Remember to try without debugging output!

Answer (score 0):

what is the name of your Form class is it

```
Manager_Form_Foo
```

where form foo is located at

```
manager/forms/Foo.php
```

Comment: It is, see my answer below - I was indirectly causing an error.